# Consuming html/json web service

Tags: html, json, oauth-2.0

Does someone know how I can consume or use this testing service for sending XML signed (invoice cross control Treasury Ministry)

```
== STAGING / SANDBOX ==

URL API RECEPTION = 

https://api.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/recepcion-sandbox/v1/

OAUTH 2.0 ACCESS TOKEN URL = 

https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token

        CLIENT ID = api-­stag
        CLIENT SECRET = [VACIO]                   
        SCOPE = [VACIO]

Language traduction:
VACIO = EMPTY
```

Comment: This is the api documentation: https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2016/v4.1/comprobantes-electronicos-api.html

Comment: With java se and c# I cannot add the web service client and service reference. Wich technologies should use?

Comment: Were you able to do this task???

Answer (score 0):

Very good,
Passing the json data in the url post and get method.
Is something like this.!

```
    https://api.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/recepcion-sandbox/v1/{
      "id": "50601011600310112345600100010100000000011999999999",
      "date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00-0600",
      "transmitter": {
        "idType": "02",
        "idNumber": "003101123456"
      },
      "receiver": {
        "idType": "02",
        "idNumber": "003101123456"
      },
      "xmlInvoice": "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pg0KDQo8ZG9tYWluIHhtbG5zPSJ1cm46amJvc3M6ZG9tYWluOjQuMCI+DQogICAgPGV4dGVuc2lvbnM+DQogICAgICAgIDxleHRlbnNpb24gbW9kdWxlPSJvcmcuamJvc3MuYXMuY2x1c3RlcmluZy5pbmZpbmlzcGFuIi8+DQogICAgICAgIDxleHRlbnNpb24gbW9kdWxlPSJvcmcuamJvc3MuYXMuY2x1c3RlcmluZy5qZ3JvdXBzIi8+DQogICAgICAgIDxleHRlbnNpb24gbW9kdWxlPSJvcmcuamJvc3MuYXMuY29ubmVjdG9yIi8+DQogICAgICAgIDxleHRlbnNpb24gbW..."
    }
```

"xmlInvoice": {
      "description": "XML electronic invoice signed by the taxpayer using XAdES-EPES. The XML text must be converted to a byte array and encoded in Base64. The character map to use in XML and in Base64 encoding is UTF8.",
      "type": "string"
    }